# animate only div instead of whole page when clicking on link in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I developing a site using jQuery, CSS and HTML. The page has on the left side a static menu which should always be shown and a content div. When I press a link in the menu right now, the whole page animates and slides to left revealing the div which the menu element links to using href. I would very much like to modify this so only the content div animates and is replaced. Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Please post some code, so we know what we're working with

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Without some code there is not much more I can give you. This is as generic as I can get:

```
$(".menuLink").click(function() {
    var linkedContent = ...identify the content being moved into view...
    var currentContent = ...identify the content being moved from view...

    var moveOldTo = "-=" + currentContent.width() + "px";
    //assuming your content divs are relatively positioned
    currentContent.animate({ left: moveOldTo }, 1000);

    var moveNewTo = "-=" + linkedContent.width() + "px";
    linkedContent.animate({ left: moveNewTo }, 1000);
});
```